# How to set the variable instrumentationKey for azure monitoring in a spring boot application

Tags: java, azure, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring

I have a issue to setup azure monitoring in spring boot project.

i have the error at each start:

> instrumentationKey must be set to report metrics to Azure Monitor.

i have set the application.properties with the following properties:

> azure.application-insights.instrumentation-key=VALID-UUID
>
> spring.application.name=test

the dependency of the project looks like:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-spring-boot-metrics-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: i create a test application with the issue. here https://github.com/RolfJordi/test-azure-monitoring.

Answer (score 1):

As per this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/micrometer-java#using-spring-2x documentation you need to add application-insights-springboot-starter as well.

Otherwise, you can set key as `azuremonitor.instrumentationKey`. My recommendation would be to add application-insights-springboot-starter along with azure-spring-boot-metrics-starter

Answer (score 0):

Tracing by dependency

- [azure-spring-boot-metrics-starter](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-spring-boot/blob/master/azure-spring-boot-starters/azure-spring-boot-metrics-starter/pom.xml)azure-spring-boot-metrics-starter -->
- [micrometer-registry-azure-monitor](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/tree/master/implementations/micrometer-registry-azure-monitor) -->
- com.microsoft.azure:applicationinsights-core

Your error message come from [AzureMonitorConfig](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/master/implementations/micrometer-registry-azure-monitor/src/main/java/io/micrometer/azuremonitor/AzureMonitorConfig.java)

So I think the key be modify to

```
azuremonitor.instrumentationKey
```

Comment: i don't use azure-application-insights-spring-boot-starter but azure-spring-boot-metrics-starter

Comment: The result was trace by dependency azure-spring-boot-metrics-starter  --> icrometer-registry-azure-monitor --> com.microsoft.azure:applicationinsights-core.
Your error message come from https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/master/implementations/micrometer-registry-azure-monitor/src/main/java/io/micrometer/azuremonitor/AzureMonitorConfig.java